# Newb question: Is it OK for the outside of my power supply to touch these metal brackets and screws?

Tags: current, safety

This is a newb question regarding safety...

I am using a piece of wood to hold a few electronics boards in place physically. I want to use these metal L brackets and screws into the plywood to secure them.

Is this safe? I know about metal-touching-metal probably isn't good, but nothing too specific. What kind of considerations should I worry about?

Picture below

[image]

EDIT - datasheet:

http://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/pdf/S-350-60.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The power supply case should be grounded via the green wire in the AC power cord, and the mounting brackets will have no other electrical connection, so there will be no problem - however, ensure that any screws holding the brackets to the power supply DO NOT touch any electrical components inside the supply.

Comment: I don't think anything inside is exposed, unless the case of the PSU itself is touching something critical. So if the brackets and screws are just going into wood... all good?

Comment: @JDS: If you use long screws to attach the brackets to the power supply, those screws could touch active components inside the case.  If you aren't actually fastening your brackets to the case, there will be no problem with contacting active components (other than the terminal strip).

Comment: @PeterBennett There appears to be a lot of metalwork around the wood. Would you recommend connecting that securely to the mains earth too?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, for safety all that ironmongery ought to be Earthed. A bolted and tagged connection onto the power supply case would be good.